# Контекстное меню в QTableView и QEventLoop

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qmenu, contextmenu

Я создаю контекстное меню стандартным путем:

```
        QMenu contextMenu(tr("Context menu"), this);
        QAction action1(tr("Копировать"), this);
        QAction action2(tr("Выделить все"), this);

        contextMenu.addAction(&action1);
        contextMenu.addAction(&action2);

        contextMenu.exec(mapToGlobal(pos));
```

Но появляющееся окно получается модальным - блокирует поток, пока я не выберу что-нибудь или не отменю открытие меню, например, кнопкой `Esc`.
Я использую QEventLoop, что позволяет мне в одном потоке обрабатывать события пользователя и производить некоторые другие несложные операции - работа с файлом, несложные повторяющиеся вычисления.
Пробовал принудительно делать меню немодальным:

```
contextMenu.setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModality::NonModal);
```

но меню после этого перестало появляться.
Также я пробовал использовать

```
        contextMenu.show();
и
        contextMenu.popup(mapToGlobal(pos));
```

но и это не помогло.
Кто знает, как сделать контекстное меню немодальным, либо почему после принудительной установки `contextMenu.setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModality::NonModal);` меню перестало появляться?
`QEventLoop` я использую по методике от [PavelK](https://pavelk.ru/qeventloop-and-connectdisconnect-lambda-function/), и проблем не возникает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так работает нормально:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->tableView->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
    connect(ui->tableView, &QTableView::customContextMenuRequested, [&](const QPoint& pos) {
        static QMenu* menu = nullptr;

        if (!menu) {
            menu = new QMenu();
            menu->addAction(new QAction("Action 1", this));
            menu->addAction(new QAction("Action 2", this));
            menu->addAction(new QAction("Action 3", this));
        }
        menu->popup( mapToGlobal(pos) );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Методы `exec()` в Qt работают по одному принципу. Они создают внутри себя `QEventLoop` и ждут пока по определённому условию не вызовется его слот `quit()`. Эта идея аналогична той, которую я вижу по вашей ссылке.

При этом локальный `QEventLoop` осуществляет доставку всех эвентов по местам назначения.

**Почему `exec()` блокирует выполнение ваших методов?**

К сожалению, не видя вашего кода, я могу лишь предположить, но вероятно вы в своих методах ждёте выхода из *своего* `QEventLoop`, в то время как он прерывается `QEventLoop`, который вызван в `exec()`. Поэтому выхода из вашего `QEventLoop` не произойдёт, пока не произойдёт выхода из `QEventLoop` метода `exec()`.

Таким образом модальность меню тут совсем не причём. Более того, QMenu по умолчанию `NonModal`, а значит вызов `contextMenu.setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModality::NonModal);` не должен был поменять принцип работы программы.

Для исправления данной проблемы вам стоит использовать обычные эвенты и сигнал/слоты там, где это возможно. Локальный `QEventLoop` будет доставлять их даже во время исполнения `QMenu::exec()`. Ещё в приложении имеется свой `QEventLoop`, который запустится при вызове app.exec() и будет отвечать за доставку эвентов в остальное время.

**Почему не работает `QMenu::popup`?**

Вызов `popup` «асинхронный» (Если быть точным, то просто видимый эффект от него будет, когда приложение начнёт обрабатывать эвенты). После его вызова выполнение программы продолжается, объект `QMenu` уничтожается при выходе из области видимости, и вы даже не успеваете его увидеть. Обойти это можно используя `new` [см.отв.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1474400/529836).

`show()` вообще не нужно использовать для `QMenu`.

Comment: exec синхронный, т.е. блокирующий вызов. popup - неблокирующий, поэтому требует, чтобы QMenu и все QAction где-то хранились в памяти.

Comment: @Eugeny, я понимаю. Моей целью было объяснить почему он синхронный, и как это конфликтует с вызовом `QEventLoop` приведённым по ссылке в вопросе. Касательно `popup` я сослался на ваш ответ, как иллюстрацию идеи. Мне всегда казалось, что говорить о проблеме более действенно в формате причина/следствие. Если стоит что-то дописать/дополнить, можно попросить немного больше конкретики? В моём представлении я вышеуказанное изложил.

Comment: @Eugeny, извините, не на ваш ответ, перепутал.

Comment: Да все отлично, все работает, спасибо!

Comment: @Eugeny, и если вносить уточнения, то exec не чисто «синхронный». Он не блокирует текущий тред, который всё ещё будет обрабатывать эвенты и вызывать слоты. Поэтому в документации qt зачастую указано избегать его использования т.к. это поведение может привести к ошибкам.

Comment: Возможно при вызове exec обрабатываются события, связанные с работой с запущенным окном?

Answer (score 0):

Как все заработало у меня:

```
    QMenu *m_contextMenu = nullptr;
    QAction *m_action1 = nullptr, *m_action2 = nullptr;
```

...

```
connect(this, &QTableView::customContextMenuRequested,
    [&] (const QPoint &pos) {
    if (!m_contextMenu) {
        m_contextMenu = new QMenu(tr("Context menu"), this);

        if (!m_action1) {
            m_action1 = new QAction(tr("Копировать"), this);
            connect(m_action1, &QAction::triggered, this, &MyTableView::copyRow);
        }

        if (!m_action2) {
            m_action2 = new QAction(tr("Выделить все"), this);
            connect(m_action2, &QAction::triggered, this, &QAbstractItemView::selectAll);
        }

        m_contextMenu->addAction(m_action1);
        m_contextMenu->addAction(m_action2);
    }
    m_contextMenu->popup(mapToGlobal(pos));
});
```

`static` мне не подошел, т.к. я использую несколько таблиц. Поэтому пришлось все вынести в члены класса.